# How to install pkg to julia without console

Tags: julia, package

Start to learn Julia recently. And do not want to use console ever.
How can I install a new package from IDE, with no use of console commands? I'm using Juno, but I'm opened to change IDE if Juno does not support such a feature. Than the question is - what IDE does?

Comment: If you google "how to install packages in Julia" you're referenced to the Julia Docs https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/packages/ that tell you exactly what the comments did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate commands from a script. Just type `Pkg.add` into a script and Ctrl+Enter on it. But I don't think avoiding the console entirely is a good way to program though!

Comment: That works, yet I was think about something like nuget or at least anything "more gui" than this.

Answer (score 1):

Write a script

```
Pkg.add("Distributions")
```

and run it.